# Ionic 3: Google Maps Place Autocomplete work only once

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, google-places-api, ionic3

I’m working on ionic 3 and I have add the Google Maps Place Autocomplete to an input tag.
I have add these pieces of code:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOyCVi_EH1cPheAu12hzDj5r3IrBtT6Ng&libraries=places"></script>
```

**page-controller.ts**

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  let places = document.getElementById('city').children[0];
  let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(places);
}
```

but it works only once, when I refresh page.

In fact, if I click on the save button in the pageController (that save user data and bring me back in homeController) and I return on this page, the Autocomplete doesn’t work anymore.

Can someone help me please?